# Major performance degradation with named parameters and preventing sql injection using hibernate with native sql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-server-2008, sql-injection

I'm using hibernate 3.6.4.Final and sql server 2008 r2 and got a query on a table with more than 20 million records. Criteria api does unfortunatly generate sub-optiomal queries when paging (`select top 100010 from ...` for result 100000 - 100010 ) when using `firstResult` / `maxResult` so I've reverted to native sql.

This queries run blazingly fast in sql studio but using named or positional parameters in hibernate those queries crawl painfully slow. Googling along I couldn't find any solution so I'm currently concatenating parameters which allows sql injections, but this is of course no option for production!

Now I'm wondering if there's something I've overlooked or at least some hibernate api or library I'm not aware of which I could use to sanitize parameters before rolling my own and probably failing to catch some edge case...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Criteria API is the best way to avoid sql injection, but it is so slow, the best way is to use normal Hibernate Queries with dynamic parameters, i mean For ex:

```
String stringQuery ="select * from User as u where id = :id";

Query query=session.createQuery(stringQuery);
query.setParameter("id",12);
```

OR u can make your query more dynamic by creating a new Class MyQueryBuilder

```
public class myQueryBuilder(){

     public Query buildQuery(int id){
       String stringQuery ="select * from User as u where u.id = :id";
       Query query=session.createQuery(stringQuery);
       query.setParameter("id",12);
       return query;
     }

    public Query buildQuery(int id,String name){
       String stringQuery ="select * from User as u where u.id = :id and u.name = :name";
       Query query=session.createQuery(stringQuery);
       query.setParameter("id",12);
       query.setParameter("name",name);
       return query;
     }

     ...
//Later you can call the query builder methods as you want depending on your params
}
```

and remember that it is always safe using setParameter() Method

Comment: Using hql is not possible for the same reason as using criteria is no option: pagination via `setMaxResults` and `setFirstResult` generates a query returning too much data most of which is discarded anyway. Eg. `setMaxResults(10)` and `setFirstResult(100000)` will load 100010 entries from the database: `select top 100010 ...`

Comment: if you want to paginate : use the following code to execute ur queries String sqlString = myQueryBuilder.buildQuery(5).unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();
then concat : sqlString += "  limit x,y";

Comment: `limit` is a MySQL-specific and is not available in MS SQL Server. The same technique is not applicable because pagination requires a nested query like `with X as (select t.*, row_number over(order by ...) as row from table t) select * from X where row >= x and row < y` which would require inserting the row_number function into the hibernate generated query and adding an outer query ...